# document.getelementbyid isnt able to get textcontent

Tags: jquery, ajax, xhtml

Based on my search on internet I found that I have to set an onclick event to my code so  I have changed the jQuery function to be called on click as bellow:

```
$.fn.addcart = function(item) {       
    alert ("im running ");
    // Create a new AJAXPaypalCart Object
    var cart = $('#cart').DCAJAXPaypalCart({
        width:600,
        autoOpenWhenAdd:true,
        openNewCheckOutWindow:true,
        //themeColor:'#333',
        //themeDarkColor:'#FFF',
        header:'Globuy Shopping Cart',
        footer:'We accpet paypal, visa and master card, Sberbank, Bank of China, Persian Bank',
        paypalOptions:{
            business:'tsangwl@digicrafts.com.hk',
            page_style:'digicrafts'
        }
    });        

    // Add the button
    cart.addBuyButton("#macbook",{
        name:"test", 
        // Item name appear on the cart
        thumbnail:'media/macbook.jpg',      // Thumbnail path of the item (Optional)
        price : $('#pricetag').text(), 
        // Cost of the item
        shipping:20             // Shipping cost for the item (Optional)
    });

    // For code highlight
    prettyPrint();
};
```

here is PHP dynamically generated shopping cart

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
$pic =  'image/'.$row['2'];
echo "<li><div class='prod_boxpage'>
    <div class='center_prod_box'>
      <div class='product_title'><a href='http://www.free-css.com/'>Makita 156 MX-VL</a>    </div>
      <div class='product_img'><a   href='http://www.free-css.com/'><img src='".$pic."' alt='".htmlspecialchars($row['1'])."' width='50' height='50' class='pngfix' /></a></div>

      <div class='prod_price'><span class='reduce'>350$</span> <span class='price'><a id='pricetag'>270</a>$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='prod_details_tab'> 


    <div class='caption'>
        <div class='text'>
             <div class='sub'>



              </div>
       </div>
          <div class='button' id='macbook' onClick='$(this).addcart('item');'><a class='prod_buy' >Add to Cart</a> <a class='prod_details'>Details</a> </div>
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>

      </li>
```

My current problem is I can't get the jQuery function running on click. Is there anything wrong with my onclick passing argument?? It's supposed to add the price from pricetag to the shopping cart. Please help.

Comment: Your code is working fine (http://jsfiddle.net/6KskK/2/). Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no error, just nothing is happening, it supposed to open the popup shopping cart and add the item,

Answer (score 4):

Try using jQuery:

```
...
price : $('#pricetag').text(), // document.getElementById("pricetag").textContent,
...
```

Comment: Failing the above you could use .html()

Comment: I have changed the calling ajax function method to onclick but the function wont be called on click, im still trying to figure out why? please suggest me some way here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this jQuery work?

```
$('#pricetag').val();
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as it's an `a` element being selected. You could use `parseFloat($(this).text())` instead.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't catch that. I glazed over and thought it was a `span` based on how he is using it.